# Notebook Box in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a notebook in asp.net web/app, which has prefix of Username and current time, and then user starts to type after that.

Like this

**Monu 11/11/2009 37 min. ago said : blah blah sadgggsddshdhs**

and on every enter press, the line should break and

**Monu 11/11/2009 30 min. ago said :**

starts again. This prefix text should not be editable, only the text that follows it.

Any pointers and suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: Monu, could you be more specific? This can be solved a milion ways.  What part of the problem do you need help with exactly?

Comment: Actully i m stuck . how to Monu 11/11/2009 37 min. ago said this appear without postback on enter click and make it uneditable !!!

Comment: @Monu - I just edited to hopefully clarify your question

Comment: Are you intending to allow editing of all the text other than the timestamps? i.e. can you go back above the timestamp to a previous bit of text and edit that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouyld make an AJAX call to get "Monu 11/11/2009 30 min ago said" every time the user press enter. Your method should have a timestamp so you can calculate the time offset for displaying "30 min" and a string that will take whatever the user has typed in. This can be easily achieved with jQuery and web services ....